# How to control the command shell through ant?

Tags: ant

currently im calling a batch script(__Make.bat) through exec task which starts GNUMake related tasks.

After i invoke build.xml file directly from the command line the batch script gets called where a new command shell is shown and before the batch script completes its operation the ant execution is closed.

Based on the output of the batch script im calling junit results task for generating the report.

So currently the batch script is independent of ant shell.

Could you please let me know is there any option to control the batch script so that after it completes its operation the junit results gets called.

snippet:

```
<!-- Macro to execute batch script from every testcase--> 
<macrodef name="executeTarget">
   <attribute name="option" default="NOT SET"/>
   <sequential>
     <exec dir="${baseLoc}/Temp/${ant.project.name}/${testDataZipFile}/MakeWare/BCU_MakeWare" executable="cmd" vmlauncher="true" os="Windows XP">
         <env key="WAHL" value="@{option}"/>
            <arg line="/c "/>
            <arg value="start __Make.bat"/>
     </exec>
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

regards,

kiran

Comment: Wat i need is How do you get the control back to ant from the batch script(executed in new window) ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `/WAIT` option to `start`:

```
<arg value="start /WAIT __Make.bat"/>
```

[Start command: Microsoft's documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx)